# How to create direction arrows for my polylines in Google Maps (V3)?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, polyline

I have routes as Google Maps Polylines in my project (an example, http://rutasgdl.com/rutas/626-2 ) and I want to add direction arrows to the routes. I want something like this (sadly, it is for Google Maps V2) http://wtp2.appspot.com/ArrowLine.htm

Can you point me in the right direction in order to achieve this? Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a blog entry by Pavel Zotov, where he describes a way to add arrows to a polyline.
The trick is to extend google.maps.OverlayView.

http://yab.hot-line.su/javascript/polyline-with-arrows-in-google-maps-api-v3.html

(I don't know if I can reproduce the code here, so I only post a link to the blog entry.)

Comment: The above blog is now unavailable (forbidden 403 error).  An alternative source is: www.wolfpil.de/v3/arrow-heads.html (again, license is unclear so I'm not sure if I can past the code in).

Answer (score 7):

The Google Maps API now supports this natively (as of July 2012).

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols#add_to_polyline

Comment: I think this link is now at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols#add_to_polyline

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code from Bill Chadwick ported to v3

Enjoy!

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B4WFC4iBvLilOHc1YTFnakFsdWM

Comment: Small bug in your code:

    strokeColor:this.color,
    strokeOpacity:this.opacity,
    strokeWeight:this.weight,

Must be:

    strokeColor:this.headColor,
    strokeOpacity:this.headOpacity,
    strokeWeight:this.headWeight,

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is use add a short line segment angled back 45 degrees to the end of the line. This thread is 10 years old but I still dont find a built in arrow to use in Google Earth. Bob Fontaine